# c++11 thread bug in visual studio 2013?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I recently find that when I tried to use c++11's thread in visual studio 2013, it generate bigger object file and exe file in release mode than debug mode. Is this indicate that the obj file contains more information in release mode that debug mode? That's so weird. Moreover, in debug mode,  I tried to debug the program step by step, but the break point and step can not be located as I set in the source file, this behavior is just like in the release mode in which the program does not exactly correspond to the source file due to optimization. So can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: The release mode size differences can be because of more aggressive inlining.

Comment: That is a possible reason. But as I can not debug the program step by step, I think that the obj file in debug mode doesn't contain enough information.

Comment: Maybe post the build log from the debug configuration in case some of the projects settings for debugging aren't set as usual.

Comment: Optimized builds often restructure code so it no longer matches the source code line by line.  This is expected behavior.

Comment: @RetiredNinja, I know this point. But normally in debug mode the program does match the source code line by line.